# Record Audio Using Microphone Connected to Remote Client

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, microphone, recording, windows-server-2019

I wish to record audio using USB microphone plugged directly to a PC with Windows Server 2019 OS. This PC will be placed in a remote place (laboratory) for research purpose. I also want to access this PC remotely through Remote Desktop Connection to activate the recording application.
[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgPR7.png)

However, when I tried to access this remote PC, I saw no audio recording device appears on sound setting.
[Audio Device Not Recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmMw7.png)

The only to make it works is to completely disable audio redirection by:

- Remote Desktop Connection Client >> Local Resources >> Remote Audio >> Play on Remote Computer

But, if I do this, I will not be able to hear any sound of remote PC from my local PC.

Is there any way to use audio recording device (USB microphone) connected directly to remote PC, but at the same time also listen to sound of remote PC from my local PC?

Any info will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: This may be one of those instances where activating it locally, & then remoting in may work [it works for video-based sources which otherwise will not run from the remote instance, because you're using 'bad' graphics drivers]. Set up a batch script with a delay to activate the recording; then log out. Log back in after the recording has started.

Comment: This might be a case where you will need to have an audio loopback device. Then it can duplicate the audio stream into one that is available for recording on the machine itself, and one that is available for listening through the remote connection.